# Best way of saving password into blackberry memory

Tags: java, blackberry, storage, password-protection

I'm developing an application for blackberry 4.6.1. 
I need to store user's password (typical feature that allows you save your password so you don't need to type it again). I was thinking of store it in a file into the device but I don't know if it's a good idea because anyone who can connect the device to the PC could get this file.

Of course the content of this will be encrypted but I still think that is not safe. As a far as I know, iOS define or setup a piece of hard-disk for each application so user cannot access to this, making storage safer, but I don't know if Blackberry have something similar.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better option is the PersitentStore, which by itself may be enough. The password could still be extracted from the device, but it would be somewhat more difficult. If this is still a problem you can take advantage of access controls. See [this developers' guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29299/Security_of_persistent_objects_1253846_11.jsp).